# Display Fetched Data from API in react native table component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-table

As I am new to react native I don't know how to do this.want to show fetched data from API in react native table like if there is 10 user then it should display 10 users data in table format.

```
export default class LeaveApprove extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     data:[]
      tableHead: ['S.No', 'NAme', 'Title'],
      tableData: [
        ['1', 'RAm', 'Manager',],
        ['2', 'Rahul', 'Admin',],
        ['3', 'Rohit', 'Accounts'],
  ],


    }
  }
   componentDidMount(){
        const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
        fetch(url,{
          method:'GET'
        })
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(data =>{
        this.setState({data:data})
        })
      }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
   <ScrollView horizontal={true} vertical={true}>

              <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}} style={{height:'100%'}}>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text} widthArr={[46,50,65,65,40,80,150]}/>
          <Rows data={state.tableData} style={styles.row}  textStyle={styles.text} widthArr={[46,50,65,65,40,80,150]} />
        </Table>

          </ScrollView>


    </Container>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You had declared your fetched inf in data variable but you are not using it any where in the component

Comment: that what I need to know I want to display data fetched from API and show in a row(state.tableData).For eg if my API contains id, name, title, etc..of 10 users how i can show it in Rows Data. I fetched the data and stored in the state don't know steps after that

Comment: <Rows data={state.data} try this

Comment: So for that case i have to keep my tabledata state an empty array... How a particular value get displayed like Sno--contain id,name colums contain user name, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside render() first destructure the data, like:

**const {data} = this.state;**

Then inside the table

```
<Rows data={data.tableData} style={styles.row}  textStyle={styles.text} widthArr={[46,50,65,65,40,80,150]} />
```

Comment: I tried but it's going blank a white screen nothing else  tableData: [
```This section data need to get from API as u can see the url contain 10 users data with id and titlesetc..```

        ['1', 'Ram', 'ADmin'],
        ['2', 'Rahul', 'Manager',],
        ['3', 'Rohit', 'Accounts',],
        
     
      ],